# Remove line feed (LF) from XML node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, linefeed, lf

I have the following in an XML node:

```
<TR_Comment>XXX YYY ZZZ
</TR_Comment>
```

(as you can see there is a line feed)

My XSLT is really simple:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a:Common/a:TR_Comment"/>
```

How can I remove the line feed using XSLT?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more precise solution than the currently accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `normalize-space(a:Common/a:TR_Comment)` do what you want?

If you are really keen on preserving inner whitespace, it can get a bit inelegant. One way is to make a recursive template that uses `string-length` and `substring` to keep removing characters from the end, one at a time, until there is no trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
translate(., '&#10;&#13;', '')
```

when this expression is evaluated, the result is the string value of the current node from which any NL or CR characters are removed.

**Do note** that no other characters are deleted or modified, so this is a more precise solution and may be preferrable in some cases over `normalize-space()`